# Chaining queries - Can't get AND/OR working

Tags: php, sql, mysql, codeigniter

After analyzing my issue, I think I may need to use the "union" operator in SQL, however I'm unsure. Anywho I'm chaining my queries in codeigniter to come out with this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (`deals`)
WHERE `category` = 'books'
AND `host` = 'amazon'
OR `host` = 'zappos'
OR `host` = 'newegg'
ORDER BY `time` desc
```

So it selects things that aren't in the category books, but are from those hosts. So I'm looking to make it so it returns only results in books, AND have a host of any of those three. I would prefer doing this with a database query rather than manually filtering afterwards.
I am using MySQL with an innoDB table. Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use brackets to make it work as desired.

```
SELECT *
FROM (`deals`)
WHERE `category` = 'books'
AND ( `host` = 'amazon'
OR `host` = 'zappos'
OR `host` = 'newegg' )
ORDER BY `time` desc
```

Or use the 'IN' keyword:

```
SELECT *
FROM (`deals`)
WHERE `category` = 'books'
AND `host` IN ( 'amazon', 'zappos', 'newegg' )
ORDER BY `time` desc
```

Comment: I think the IN clause is the best option

Comment: I agree that the IN clause would make the most logical sense here :)

Answer (score 0):

Try some parentheses:

```
SELECT *
FROM (`deals`)
WHERE `category` = 'books'
AND ( 
`host` = 'amazon'
OR `host` = 'zappos'
OR `host` = 'newegg'
)
ORDER BY `time` desc
```